# The Vibrant Periodical

Tags: mathematics, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The image below will allow you to find a nine-letter word that describes the nature of this puzzle. Good luck!

[image]

Text Version:

```
N P R Y O Y K K R       Y K P S R S B B N
R N L O S S B N O       P K S R K K W S Y
O K N Y G O G S R       G S Y S B L K P L
Y O L N K B N O B       N S K P N L S Y W
B L O O L O Y R P   +   G G P P S L G Y W
G S P O B O K B K       R R S N R N G P G
Y B P Y P P G G N       K S L B B G P W W
O K S R P B B G B       W L R W B N Y W Y
B P B P S B S N O       S Y P B P R L W B

R: Red         B: Blue
O: Orange      N: Navy
Y: Yellow      P: Purple
L: Lime Green  K: Pink
G: Green       W: Brown
S: Sky Blue
```

*Note: Neither the names I have given the colors nor the letters used to represent them are used to solve the puzzle.*

**Hint:**

> [image: hint 1]

**Hint 2:**

> There are more mathematical concepts involved that you might first expect.

**Hint 3:**

> If at first you don't succeed, try, try again.

**Hint 4:**

> Each color brings something useful to the puzzle. Though not necessarily all at the same time.

Comment: Do you have a text version of the two grids (say, using a different letter for each color)?

Comment: I will happily make one. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Welp, pretty sure I know the final answer via the hint, but not how to exactly get to it :)

Comment: @Lukas Rotter I may need to work on my hint-giving. I wish you the best of luck with solving, though! : )

Comment: Pretty sure I figured out how to use the hint (and how to get to it), but I'm not sure how to get to the final answer after that! :)

Comment: For reference: https://pastebin.com/jEUqMAkf. Only thing I see immediately is that the Ws of A+B+A look like an S

Comment: Ah, of course, now I get it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The nine-letter word is

> Recursive

Explanation

> As per hint #1, adding two grids together means adding the numeric values of the two cells (given by the color strip), dividing it by 11 (= number of colors) and taking the remainder as the result.
> [image]
> [image]
>  The arrow in the image suggests we need to do something further with the result of adding both grids together. At first I thought A<sub>-1</sub> means "inverse of grid", but with hints #3 and #4 it became clear that this actually hints towards a sequence! I.e. "Sequence A index -1".
>  So if we just keep on adding the first grid to the result of our previous  calculation, we can see something peculiar on our first try:
> [image]
>  Looks like the brown cells form the shape of the letter `S`, which yields the first actual letter of the sequence! Let's do it 10 more times to cover all colors, i.e. keep on adding the first grid to our current result:
> [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]
>  This gives us two invalid shapes (for Y/O's turn), so ignore those. The rest gives us `suceevirr`, which is an anagram of the answer, `RECURSIVE`.

Comment: Wonderful job. Congratulations on the solve.

Comment: Additional Note: rot13(Vs lbh erphefviryl nqq gur Frpbaq tevq, vg fcryyf gur jbeq erphefvir va beqre bs pbybe.)